# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Drupal Answers breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5         18
Users destroyed                                 800          0
Users deleted                                    97          0
Users contacted                                  15          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           247      2,713
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               42      1,044
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          0      1,202
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0      1,214
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1      3,180
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              164      4,599
Tags merged                                     217          0
Revisions redacted                               14          0
Questions reopened                               87          5
Questions protected                              18         29
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions merged                                  9          0
Questions flagged⁴                              137     12,538
Questions closed                              1,976        527
Question flags handled⁴                       1,051     11,624
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                  56        144
Posts locked                                      7      2,103
Posts deleted⁵                                1,029      7,853
Posts bumped                                      0      8,728
Escalations to the CM team                        9          0
Comments undeleted                                7          0
Comments flagged                                  0      1,998
Comments deleted⁶                             1,768      2,991
Comment flags handled                           600      1,398
Bounties canceled                                 2          0
Answers flagged                                  29      1,718
Answer flags handled                          1,270        477
All comments on a post moved to chat             29          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...